# Java Date, render with specific daylight mode

Tags: java, datetime, date, timezone, dst

I have a Java `Date` that is from this summer during daylight savings time. For example:

> Jun 01, 2009 06:00 AM PDT

My question is, how do I display this date as my local time zone and **current daylight savings mode** (in my case Pacific Standard Time)?

> Jun 01, 2009 05:00 AM PST

Java's `Date.toString()` and `SimpleDateFormat` displays the date in the **original** daylight savings mode. Example:

```
System.out.println(new Date(1243861200000L));
```

outputs:

> Mon Jun 01 06:00:00 PDT 2009

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm aa zzz");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date(1243861200000L)));
```

outputs:

> Jun 01, 2009 06:00 AM PDT

What I really want to see is 5:00 AM PST (which is equivalent to 6:00 AM PDT). Is there a way to force it to use another daylight savings mode?

**Follow up:** By the way, this is the Windows XP behavior. A file created on June 1, 6 AM will be seen (by Explorer, Command Prompt, etc) as June 1, 5 AM during the winter.

Comment: It is mandatory on SO that whenever somebody asks a question about Dates in Java to mention Joda Time.  I have no idea if it will do what you want, but it's mandatory.

Comment: I think someone does not have their head on straight. Who is asking for this? It makes no sense. Date/times are fixed in DSMode and only vary by TZ (geographic shift).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to force the `DateFormat` to apply a `TimeZone` format to a time that couldn't exist.  PST is only applicable in the Winter months and PDT is only used in the summer.

I formatted this date with all of the `TimeZone`s returned by `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`, and found two that returned me PST for that particular time: Pacific/Pitcairn and SystemV/PST8.  You could try using one of those, but I have no idea what other rules apply to either of those timezone objects.

If you're just concerned with getting the time with that offset, you could use `GMT-8` as your TimeZone.  However, that string will show up in your formatted date string instead of PST.

**UPDATE:**  Here's a way to take any timezone and have it ignore all daylight savings time rules.  You can grab a `TimeZone` object then grab another `TimeZone.getTimeZone()` object.  On the second object set the `Id` and `rawOffset` to the corresponding  object from the first `TimeZone`.

For example:

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm aa zzz");
    TimeZone defaultTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("");
    timeZone.setID(defaultTimeZone.getID());
    timeZone.setRawOffset(defaultTimeZone.getRawOffset());
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone);
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date(1243861200000L)));
```

This will print out exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

PST/PDT change throughout the year.  Java attempts to determine which one is in affect on a given date. This things obviously change as the laws and regions change.  Can you use an absolute time zone?  Specifying the offset in GMT will be the same year around.

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm aa zzz");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-07:00"));
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date(1243861200000L)));

Jun 01, 2009 06:00 AM GMT-07:00
```

Answer (score 1):

this might do the trick:

```
    /*
     * Create a date that represents 1,243,861,200,000 milliseconds since
     * Jan 1, 1970
     */
    Date date = new Date(1243861200000L);

    /*
     * Print out the date using the current system's default format and time
     * zone. In other words, this will print differently if you set the
     * operating zone's time zone differently.
     */
    System.out.println(date);

    /*
     * Specify the format and timezone to use
     */
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm aa zzz");
    TimeZone pstTZ = TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(pstTZ);
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));

    /*
     * It looks like what you want is to actually display a different date
     * (different # milliseconds since epoch) in the summer months. To do that, you
     * need to change the date by subtracting an hour.
     */
    if(pstTZ.inDaylightTime(date)){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);
        date = cal.getTime();
    }
    //now this should always print "5:00". However, it will show as 5:00 PDT in summer and 5:00 PST in the winter which are actually 2 different dates. So, I think you might need to think about exactly what it is you're trying to achieve. 
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: -1 The date will then be incorrect during the winter months, when the date is really in PST.

Comment: Thanks, Jason, I see how that's misleading, I'll update my answer to be more clear about what I was trying to show by subtracting an hour from the date.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm aa zzz"); 
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Pacific/Pitcairn")); 
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date(1243861200000L)));
```

Additional comments:  zzz will print out PST, while z will print out GMT-08:00.  TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST") works for for Eastern Standard Time, making me think this is a bug with TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST").

I suggest using predefined time zones, since they can be confusing:

```
public static final TimeZone ZONE_GREENWICH_MEAN_TIME = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
public static final TimeZone ZONE_EASTERN_DAYLIGHT_TIME = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"); // EDT, GMT-04:00
public static final TimeZone ZONE_EASTERN_STANDARD_TIME = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"); // GMT-05:00
public static final TimeZone ZONE_PACIFIC_DAYLIGHT_TIME = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"); // PDT, GTM-0700
public static final TimeZone ZONE_PACIFIC_STANDARD_TIME = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Pacific/Pitcairn"); // PST, GMT-08:00
```

I came across another time with a similar problem "2009-11-01 08:44:44".  I tried iterating over all IDs and none would print EDT.  The funny thing was that "2010-11-01 08:44:44" would print EDT.  Between 1990 and 2010, only 2007, 2008 and 2010 would print EDT.  When I checked the years from 0 to 2499, only 431 had EDT, with the first in 1940 (this must be when EDT was introduced).  So of the 560 years (1940-2499), only 431 have an ID that prints EDT.  From 1940 to 2006, there are only 10 years which have IDs which print EDT.  After 2006, every 4, 5 or 10 years, there is a year which will not print EDT.